# FireBase: Sending message from Java server to single device - not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

I have a Java backend with the following code according to the [latest documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#java):

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
String registrationToken = ".....";

Message message = Message.builder()
            .putData("score", "850")
            .putData("time", "2:45")
            .setToken(registrationToken)
            .build();

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
    String response = "";
    try {
      response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException $fme) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString($fme.getStackTrace()));
    }
```

I get the correct response in the form of `projects/project-name/messages/0:1591252388663621%d13f7b6bf5fd7edd`.

However, the Android device I got the registration token from does not receive the message. Also, the message does not appear in the [reports tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/whispers-rr/notification/reporting) of cloud messaging. Sending notifications to the registration token using the FireBase console works fine.

Comment: Backend doesn't look suspicious. Could you share code that is responsible for showing push notifications on Android? It is probable that the problem lays there. Android side implementation should implement `FirebaseMessagingService`. Skim up and down this guide, maybe you missed something https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu But like I said, sending messages via the console works fine, the frontend handles them correctly. And shouldn't the messages appear in the reporst tab?

Comment: Still it would be useful if you could share Android side code because notifications you sending from Firebase Console and notification you sending from server side could be different. Note, that if notification body contains data - this is a notification that your code must handle from receiving to parsing and showing. Try to send notification with data key-value pairs. Add them at the last step `Additional options (optional)`.

Comment: By `data` I mean contents of `RemoteMessage#getData()`. Also, if your application is in the background and it does not contain any data - it will be shown by the Android system. So you basically do not have control over them in this state on client-side.

Comment: Isn't that what I am already doing with the "score" and "time" key-value pairs?

Comment: Yes, these are key-value pairs, but as I said `this is a notification that your code must handle from receiving to parsing and showing`. For me to understand this case better: notifications you sending from Firebase Console also contain key-value pairs? Or notifications from Firebase Console simply contain title and message? *Note: with reports tab I have no experience, cannot help on that part*